# What do the skulls mean in shadow of Mordor

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

What do the white blue yellow and red skulls mean when you are looking in Saurons army and hover over an Uruk. I tried looking in the tutorials and hints option but could not find anything that explain what they meant

Answer (score 4):

The **White Skull** can be considered the generic one because it just indicates that the Uruk in question is a **Captain**

The **Blue Skull** is a Branded Uruk Captain, branded by you ofcourse.

In Battle you can have **Yellow Skulls** and **Green Skulls**. **Yellow** is when you are detected and that Uruk captain is investigating and **Green** is when he can be finished off in battle.

There is a variety of all the **Skulls** with a **Red** indicator, as you can see here:

[image: indicator]

In the picture you can see a **White Skull** with the indicator but it can be any type of skull.

Comment: Okay I got you. Thank you for the informative feedback. It's greatly appreciated. What about a captain that has a white skull over his head without the red indicator which is indicating that you targeted and are tracking that captain?

Comment: I think I said in my asnwer. A white skull means the Uruk is a captain. It's in the first line :)

Comment: Okay I was just making sure I understood you correctly. Thanks again for the advice and help.

Comment: I tried to vote it up and it says I need 15 reputation? I'm assuming I have to ask more questions and answer other questions? BTW I have another question could you explain how commands work when I am commanding a war chief, please? Such as a riot.

Comment: When you have the rep make sure to show some love :D About the question, the comments are not an appropriate place. Search the website to see if anyone has had the same question as you. If you think it's worthy of asking a question, ask a question and the community will answer :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the skulls don't turn yellow and red based on how alert they are to you. Those are the triangles over enemies' heads.  A Gold skull means it's a captain that's also a quest objective.  A Green Skull means the captain is weak and can be grabbed.